# Android app does not upgrade for a new version after download it from the server

Tags: android, server, apk

I have a problem updating a newer version of the Android app.

Every client has different requests for the app, like colours of a button, exclude some services that they do not need, etc, and they have the opportunity to upgrade it on the login app page from our server (new a new version is ready, a popup will appear).

When I upgrade for the main provider (developer debug) the app upgrades from a newer version. If I uninstall the app, and put the APK of the provider, let's call 'A', and in the login page switch for the provider 'developer debug' and try to update the app, I actually can download the APK but I can't upgrade the App, it appears 'application not installed'.

I checked the versionCode on the 'developer debug' on Gradle, and the integer is higher than the provider 'A'.

I checked the manifest as well, I did not find any conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons for this but as far as I understand you can have one of these issues:

1. Check if you actually created a release version of your app and you are not using the same debug version. Create a release from
   Android Studio

Build -> Generate Signed Packages (or some like this)

2. Even if you did create a new release package of your app, make sure its created using the same developer signing key which was used for the old or previous version of your app.